# How to fill current object (this) by another object

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I need to copy all properties from another object to curren object (this) in Kotlin. object.copy() is not solution because i can't use it on curren instance of class. Maybe by reflection. In c# it looks like this:

```
public virtual void fillFromObject(object obj){
    foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
    {
        if (property.GetSetMethod() != null)
            property.SetValue(this, obj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(obj, null), null);
    }
}
```

using:

```
this.fillFromObject(anotherObject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatic Kotlin doesn't use reflection and avoids mutable objects, so even limiting this to your own classes is a bad idea because it holds them in that paradigm. I also question your C# implementation, but in Kotlin it would look something like:

```
public fun <T: Any> T.fillFromObject(src: T, cl: KClass<out T> = src::class) {
    require(cl.isInstance(this)) { "destination object does not inherit $cl" }
    require(cl.isInstance(src)) { "source object does not inherit $cl" }
    cl.declaredMemberProperties.filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty1<T, *>>()
        .filter { it.visibility == KVisibility.PUBLIC }
        .forEach { it.setter.call(this, it.get(src)) }
}
```

Comment: While I share your concerns, “Idiomatic Kotlin… avoids mutable objects” seems to be putting it a little strongly. Certainly Kotlin supports immutability where that makes sense, and it's often a good default position — but there are also many situations where mutability is appropriate, and Kotlin allows that too. As for reflection, there are a few situations where it's needed (such as frameworks, plugins, compiler tools, and interoperability); but it's ugly, slow, fragile, insecure, and hard to read, and so a strong code smell anywhere else.